# z-index problem on IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

Any one can solve z-index problem on menu with IE7 [site removed]

Comment: Can you describe the problem a bit more? What have you tried to fix it?

Comment: For drop down menu I cant set possition with z-index on IE7

Comment: Please review this article for a work around that should address your exact issue with the z-index problem in IE7: http://brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/

Comment: I've removed a link to your site for two reasons: 1) spammy promotion, and 2) you need to actually post a code snippet in your post, otherwise this question won't be particularly helpful to anyone having a similar problem since there's nothing to compare their code against.

Answer (score 2):

“In Internet Explorer positioned elements generate a new stacking context, starting with a z-index value of 0. Therefore z-index doesn’t work correctly” (see http://www.quirksmode.org/bugreports/archives/2006/01/Explorer_z_index_bug.html)

It appears that giving the parent element a higher z-index actual fixes the bug.

see: http://brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/

```
<div style="position: relative; z-index: 3000">
    <div style="position:absolute;z-index:1000;">
        <a href="#">Page</a>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
<img style="position:absolute" src="myimage.png" />
```